# Compile error with grails 2.4.1 and plugin joda-time 1.5

Tags: grails, jodatime

When compiling a grails 2.4.1 project I get the following error:

```
[groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
[groovyc] /home/omarques/ws1/sigob/target/work/plugins/joda-time-1.5/src/groovy/grails/plugin/jodatime/simpledatastore/SimpleMapJodaTimeMarshaller.groovy: 44: Apparent variable 'MonthDay' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:
[groovyc] You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context.
[groovyc] You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.
[groovyc] You attempted to use a method 'MonthDay' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.
[groovyc]  @ line 44, column 87.
[groovyc]    me, LocalDate, LocalDateTime, MonthDay,
[groovyc]                                  ^
```

I've tried to upgrade the project to 2.4.3 and got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was solved by including on BuildConfig an explicit dependency to joda-time-2.3 because another dependency(net.objectlab.kit:datecalc-joda:1.2.0) was causing the use of an outdated version of joda-time that is incompatible with the joda-time grails plugin

Comment: An example of this can be found at: https://github.com/gpc/grails-joda-time/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to application.properties and try

plugins.joda-time=1.3.1

Comment: this version is not compatible with grails 2.4